# Android Concepts for Xamarin.Forms Developer

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on **Xamarin.forms** from almost one year, right now I am handling with notification on (PCL Android Project), I discover a lot of new Concepts for me on android(Example : `Intent`,`Context`,...), Because I did not working on native android project before.

what the basic information and concepts should be clear for **xamarin.forms** developer about android

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit, to access the native feature of each platform for example: handling `Notification`, we need to use `DependencyService` in PCL, this `DependencyService` provides a simple locator so that you can code to Interfaces in your shared code and provide platform-specific implementations that are automatically resolved.  For example:  [Toast Notifications for Xamarin Forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/toast-notifications-xamarin-forms/) and [sample code](https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin).

Comment: This is a very broad question. You could go to the [Getting Started](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) pages of the official Android documentation. Or buy/borrow a good book about Android and read the first chapters; the first chapters in any good Android book should explain these concepts.